# Ng-repeat not working expression shows and then disappears immediately

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating a list of users on this page using ng-repeat. When the page is refreshed the expression that is supposed to appear shows up for a split second and then disappears without any trace of the object that should be repeated. This is the code

```
<div class="row" data-ng-controller="createUserProfileController as dashboard">
    <h2 class="text-center">Find Students Near By</h2>
    <hr />
                <div class="col-md-6" id="map-canvas"></div>

    <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
        <div class="panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="text-center">List of Datalus Users</h3>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div ng-repeat="userProfile in dashboard.items" class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title text-center">
                        <a data-parent="#accordion1" href="/courses/moreinfo/{{userProfile.id}}">
                            {{userProfile.firstName}}
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.cols -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: whats the error in the console?

Comment: create a fiddle , it will be easy to understand. Because "dashboard.items" need to be checked

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is no error. Might be you are doing changes from somewhere else. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/uzmbneyn/) I implemented your code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uzmbneyn/).

```
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("createUserProfileController", ["$scope", function($scope){
  var c = this;
  c.items = [
    {
      id: 1,
      firstName: 'hello'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      firstName: 'bufellow'
    }
  ];
}]);
```

Comment: I am not getting any error messages. So perhaps the error may be somewhere in my script

Comment: I don't think there is any error. Might be you are updating `items` by using ajax requests.